# Reuse Jquery DropDown list with MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to make a dropdown list that I have displayed on multiple partial views that can be opened multiple times. I'm trying to get my jquery function to work with every instance instead of only being able to work with one.
Also when you select the first drop down list another dropdown list appears directly next to it with more options.

This is an example of my view

```
    <div class="pad5"><span class="FieldLabel">Application *</span><span>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GeneralID, Model.GeneralOptions, "Select", new { id = "General" })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option1ID, Model.Option1, "--Choose One--", new { id = "Option1", style = "display:none" })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option2ID, Model.Option2, "--Choose One--", new { id = "Option2", style = "display:none" })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option3ID, Model.Option3, "--Choose One--", new { id = "Option3", style = "display:none" })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option4ID, Model.Option4, "--Choose One--", new { id = "Option4", style = "display:none" })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option5ID, Model.Option5, "--Choose One--", new { id = "Option5", style = "display:none" })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option6ID, Model.Option6, "--Choose One--", new { id = "Option6", style = "display:none" })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option7, Model.Option7, "--Choose One--", new { id = "Option7", style = "display:none" })
    </span>
```

and my Jquery

```
    $('#General').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $('#General').val(); //selectedValue will get "Option7" if thats whats selected
    if (selectedValue != 0) {//Default value for select list is 0 so if you pick "Select" it will reset
        $('#' + selectedValue).show().siblings().hide();
        $('#General').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#General').siblings().hide().val(0);
    }
});
```

I've tried to get this to work with classes but I can't get the syntax right.

EDIT

```
   <span><select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ProductsID must be a number." data-val-required="The ProductsID field is required." id="General" name="ProductsID"><option value="">Select</option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
    <option>Option4</option>
    <option>Option5</option>
    <option>Option6</option>
    <option>Option7</option>
```

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AeroSpaceID must be a number." data-val-required="The Options1ID field is required." id="Option1" name="Options1ID" style="display:none"><option value="">--Choose One--</option>
<option>Choice1</option>
<option>Choice2</option>
<option>Choice3</option>
<option>Choice4</option>
<option>Choice5</option>
<option>Choice6</option>
<option>Choice7</option>
<option>Choice8</option>
<option>Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is the rendered html?

Comment: @Sushil What do you mean?

Comment: what is the html being generated with this MVC code? i can create a fiddle if i have the html

Comment: @Sushil see edit, Each of the first options have another select list that has 4-8 options.

Comment: let me see what I can do.

Comment: @Sushil Thank you very much. If you can't get anything don't worry about it.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I am not sure if this is right but can u have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/mzzkgbq2/

Comment: @Sushil Don't worry about the delay. I think this should help.

Comment: let me know if it needs some more work. I can work on it